# Find best sequence diagram solution

Tags: python, iot, mosquitto

[image: Complex Diagram]

How can CLIENT continuously receive data from SERVER? I think my sequence diagram is complex solution. I just want Client set connect with  Server 1 time then Server  continuously send data to Client anyway. Here I use API-Restful + Mosquitto

Answer (score 0):

MQTT can run over a Websocket connection so it is possible to subscribe directly to the MQTT broker from within a webpage. This would remove the need for any REST calls.

The [Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) Javascript client supports MQTT of Websockets.

The broker will need to be configured to support MQTT over Websockets on a separate port from the normal native MQTT support. Details of how to set up Mosquitto to do this can be found in the [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm407) page